# If $p_i$ are distinct primes, show that an abelian group of order $p_1p_2...p_s$ must be cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I've got a (possible) solution for this problem, but I'm not very satisfied with how I've written it down and would like some feedback.

> If $G$ is such a group, then by Cauchy we know that there exist elements in $G$ of order $p_i,\;1\leq i\leq s$; denote these elements as $g_i$.
>
> Because of Lagrange, we know that these elements must be generators for groups of order $p_i$ respectively.
>
> Let $g_i, g_j$ distinct. Then because $G$ is abelian, $(g_ig_j)^{n} = g^n_i g^n_{j}$. So $(g_ig_j)^n=e$ if and only if $g_i^n=e$ and $g_j^n=e$. Therefore the co-primeness of their orders ($p_i$ and $p_j$ are both distinct primes) ensures that $|<g_ig_j>| = p_ip_j$.
>
> Continuing this process, $|<g_1g_2...g_s>|=p_1p_2...p_s$, so $g_1g_2...g_s$ is a generator of the entire group.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct, but you should justify why $|\langle p_1'p_2'\rangle|=p_1p_2$.

Comment: How would you best write this down? Since $p_i$ and $p_j$ are distinct primes, their least common multiple is $p_ip_j$, and therefore $|<p'_ip'_j>|=p_ip_j$?

Comment: What has the least common multiple have to do with this? (What theorem are you using?)

Comment: I'm not really using any theorems for this step, just recognising that the order of $p'_i$ and $p'_j$ are $p_i$ and $p_j$, so if $(p'_ip'_j)^n=e$, then $p'^n_i=e$ and $p'^n_j = e$, so $n=k*lcm(p_i, p_j)$.

Comment: That works. Just add this little explanation in the proof and you'll be done. I think the proof looks a little bit awkward because you call the elements $p_i'$. Rather call them $g_i$ or something like that. Makes it less confusing to read and it is immediately clear that the elements $g_i$ are group elements.

Comment: So like this? :)

Comment: I don't think it is true that $(g_ig_j)^n=e\iff g_i^n =e=g_j^n$.

Comment: Take for example the additive group $G= \mathbb{Z}_6$. $g_1=\bar{2}, g_2=\bar{4}, n=2$.

Comment: It wouldn't be, because this violates the assumption that $g_i$ and $g_j$ are of distinct prime order. Here $|g_1| = |g_2| = 3$.

Comment: Yes, but it shows that the statement you say does not hold. I think it even fails under the additional assumption but can't find a quick counterexample (I'm traveling).